# How to avoid detection when accessing website through TOR browser with selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, detection, tor, brute-force

I have been trying to scrape websites for a while now, and when you apply brute force to retrieve all information on 500.000+ urls from one website, you can get blocked. Therefore, I am now trying to scrape my data through TOR browser with selenium webdriver. So far so good. Got it up and running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:/location_to/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"C:/location_to/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/Caches/profile.default")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:/Location_to/geckodriver-v0.25.0-win64/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
```

Resulting in:
Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
Your IP address appears to be: 94.230.208.147

Great. However, when I try to access certain websites I get detected:

```
driver.get("https://gearbest.com")
raw_html = driver.page_source
clean_html = soup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
```

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://gearbest.com/" on this server.
Reference #18.cff31502.1569612654.932f460

Most websites do not detect me, it is just a handful. I have tried a bunch of "solutions" but posting them would most likely be more confusing than helping. It could be headless detection, but again, I am not sure. Who can help me here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the website itself specifically blocks Tor traffic.

Comment: Can you access those site in the same browser with out selenium? have try the same in other browser in the same network?

Comment: @stacktome : I have just tried to access the website through TOR only but than it is also denied. When I try to access this website with selenium through FireFox, there is no problem.

Comment: so its some think to do with TOR not with Selenium, Maybe you need to change the setting in order to access all website in TOR

Comment: I have tried many things now. TOR bridges including costum obfs4 and meek-azure but still getting detected. I will keep trying.

Comment: That block message you are seeing is a direct result of using Tor. I believe it's Akamai blocking Tor. So you are out of luck. It's not Selenium being detected, it's Tor. You'll always get detected because all Tor exists are known. Bridges help connect, but still use publicly known exit relays. You'll need to not use Tor but spin up some VPS instances and run SOCKS proxies through them.

Comment: I have alsof tried all available free vpns and these are blocked as well. There must be some kind of way to get around Akamai right..?

Comment: A complete list of all websites blocked when accessed through TOR can be found here:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/doc/ListOfServicesBlockingTor                      Ad-hoc solutions can be found here to circumvent the blockage which involve fetching content via other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete list of all websites blocked when accessed through TOR can be found here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/doc/ListOfServicesBlockingTor Ad-hoc solutions can be found here to circumvent the blockage which involve fetching content via other websites.

For security reasons, I have switched to autoVPN (in linux in vm), which is free, not blocked by the target website, and provides high-end privacy.